# Automatically page scrolls to top when switching between tabs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
<div className="mainpanel">
  
</div>
```

**Requirement:-**
While Switching tab in the left panel,
Right Panel scroll back to the Top of the Page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a ref for the rightPanel.

You can try adding a handleTabChange callback to each tab using onClick.
Inside the handleTabChange callback, using the `ref.currentElement` set the `scrollTop` property to 0.